# PostgreSQL : variable scope in the pgAdmin debugger

Tags: debugging, postgresql, scope, pgadmin

I am trying to get to know the pgAdmin debugger and am fairly new to PostgreSQL. I don't know if the behavior I'm seeing is because of a mistake I am making or simply because of limitations in the debugger.

At the top of my function I've declared two variables:

```
   declare tuple record;
   declare buffer text;
```

In the body of my function I am trying to iterate the rows in temporary table TT_CALENDAR, so it would be possible to examine the contents of the temporary table in the Locals window:

```
for tuple in
  select startdate, enddate from TT_CALENDAR
  loop
   buffer := concat(buffer, tuple.startdate::text, tuple.enddate::text,'|');
  end loop;

 buffer :='';
```

Breakpoints are set at `buffer := concat(...` and at the line `buffer :='';` and program execution stops there as expected, but as soon as we exit the loop and arrive at `buffer :='';` the  string value vanishes from the Locals window.

Why would buffer's displayed value vanish from the Locals window when we exit the loop *before* `buffer :='';` is executed?   It's as if the variable has gone out of scope.

P.S. Is there a configuration setting that would cause long values to wrap in the Locals window **Value** cell?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a bug with the debugger.  I would generally recommend following up on the pgadmin email lists and alert the developers to this problem.

There is no reason I know that the variables would be out of scope so it sounds to me like it is a bug in the debugger itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will follow up on pgadmin. I gather they don't frequent this establishment :-)